# Magento 2 Authorize payment command

Tags: magento2.2, payment-gateway

I'm having trouble understanding how an "Authorize" command is executed in a payment method.

Magento 2 uses Javascript components for payment methods and a "Place order" click initiates the whole process, I'm just not sure how/when the Authorize request gets built & sent to a payment provider.

For example, if I use the sample payment gateway that Magento provides: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway, how is the request builder going to be called?

**EDIT**

This is a reference to Joni Jones's answer

> When Magento performs place order actions, it calls authorize or
>   capture (used for sale operation too) payment operation (according to
>   an operation configured for the selected payment method).

This is the part that I'm having trouble with.

Do I understand you correctly that the command, which is specified in the payment modules `di.xml` (authorize/capture/sale) gets automatically called when the "Place order" action gets triggered?

If so, what is the entry point, i.e. which class/file gets called first in a hypothetical situation where you have only 1 command in a command pool (e.g. the authorize command)?

And, if it's not asking too much, what is the bare minimum that you need to have to start execution of a command? Is it really enough to just have a simple custom payment method and the command specified in the payment method's `di.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Magento performs place order actions, it calls `authorize` or `capture` (used for `sale` operation [too](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php#L445)) payment operation (according to an operation configured for the selected payment method).

This action triggers a chain of methods and if your payment integration based on the Magento payment provider gateway the sales infrastructure tries to call `authorize` or `capture` payment gateway command from the [command pool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/command-pool.html).

As you can see from the documentation, the command pool contains a list of available commands, in most cases there are `authorize`, `sale`, `capture`, `refund`, `cancel`, `void` but you can specify own commands and use command pool as dependency in your classes to perform available commands.

As an example, Braintree implementation [uses](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Controller/Payment/GetNonce.php#L65) `GetPaymentNonceCommand` to generate payment nonce.

The command interaction explains [this diagram](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-structure.html) on the Magento dev docs.

**UPD**: Authorize.net has a good [tutorial](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/payment_transactions.html#Life_of_a_Transaction) about different types of payment transactions, maybe, it will help to understand why Magento has different actions like `authorize` and `capture`.

**UPD2**: When a customer clicks `Place Order` and if the default action is used(`payment-information` WEB API entry point) when Magento calls the next abstract chain:

```
Quote::submit
   ->Order::place
      ->OrderPayment::place (authorize|sale) - depends on configured payment action for a payment method
          ->PaymentAdapter::authorize|sale
              ->GatewayCommand::authorize|sale - the needed command will be read from the di.xml
                  -> ... - other payment gateway stuff
```

The "border" between Sales and Payment module is `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment::place()` and `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter::authorize()|sale()`.

For simple flow, at least you need payment method skeleton (etc folder with di.xml, module.xml, etc. - can be found in the Magento sample repository) and gateway command with related infrastructure - request builders, validations, response handlers, http|soap clients, etc.

The official documentation covers step by step all requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, most of it I understand, but the 1st paragraph I'm having trouble with. If you could share more info, please check my edit.

Comment: @Lez, please, see updated answer.

Comment: I see, so the Web API call starts the process. But what is the entry point of the authorize command? Or what is the first class and method that gets called in the scope of the authorization command?

Comment: `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter::authorize` calls authorize command. If you do not implement own command, the `\Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\GatewayCommand::execute` will ve called.